# Reading elements from a nested vector in Rust

Tags: rust, vector

I am currently looking to parse through bgp data using the crate bgpkit_parser, filtering only the as_path. This can be done with the following code:

```
use bgpkit_parser::BgpkitParser;
fn main() {
    let url: &str = "http://archive.routeviews.org/\
    route-views.chile/bgpdata/2022.06/UPDATES/updates.20220601.0000.bz2";
    let parser = BgpkitParser::new(url).unwrap();
    for elem in parser {
        println!("{:?}",  elem.as_path);
    }
}
```

This gives the following output (I've just shown one line for readability):
`Some(AsPath { segments: [AsSequence([Asn { asn: 27678, len: Bits32 }, Asn { asn: 27986, len: Bits32 }, Asn { asn: 262589, len: Bits32 }, Asn { asn: 32098, len: Bits32 }])] })`

**What I am trying to do is to just have the asn values comma separated so for the output above: `27678, 27986, 262589, 32098`.**

I have reduced the above output to `AsSequence([Asn { asn: 27678, len: Bits32 }, Asn { asn: 27986, len: Bits32 }, Asn { asn: 262589, len: Bits32 }, Asn { asn: 32098, len: Bits32 }])` by doing the following:

```
use bgpkit_parser::BgpkitParser;
fn main() {
    let url: &str = "http://archive.routeviews.org/\
    route-views.chile/bgpdata/2022.06/UPDATES/updates.20220601.0000.bz2";
    let parser = BgpkitParser::new(url).unwrap();
    for elem in parser {
        println!("{:?}",
            elem.as_path.unwrap().segments[0]);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to go about doing the rest. I have added some further information below on what I think may be relevant. Thank you!

```
pub struct BgpElem {
    pub timestamp: f64,
    pub elem_type: ElemType,
    pub peer_ip: IpAddr,
    pub peer_asn: Asn,
    pub prefix: NetworkPrefix,
    pub next_hop: Option<IpAddr>,
    pub as_path: Option<AsPath>,
    pub origin_asns: Option<Vec<Asn>>,
    pub origin: Option<Origin>,
    pub local_pref: Option<u32>,
    pub med: Option<u32>,
    pub communities: Option<Vec<MetaCommunity>>,
    pub atomic: Option<AtomicAggregate>,
    pub aggr_asn: Option<Asn>,
    pub aggr_ip: Option<IpAddr>,
}
```

```
/// Enum of AS path segment.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Eq)]
pub enum AsPathSegment {
    AsSequence(Vec<Asn>),
    AsSet(Vec<Asn>),
    ConfedSequence(Vec<Asn>),
    ConfedSet(Vec<Asn>),
}

impl AsPathSegment {
    pub fn count_asns(&self) -> usize {
        match self {
            AsPathSegment::AsSequence(v) => {
                v.len()
            },
            AsPathSegment::AsSet(_) => 1,
            AsPathSegment::ConfedSequence(_) | AsPathSegment::ConfedSet(_)=> 0,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Eq)]
pub struct AsPath {
    pub segments: Vec<AsPathSegment>,
}
```

```
/// ASN -- Autonomous System Number
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Copy, Deserialize, Eq)]
pub struct Asn {
    pub asn: u32,
    pub len: AsnLength,
}
```

Comment: Is your question how to get `println!` to print this cleaner?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I think I am more interested in how I can map through the values so that I can access for example asn:27678. But yes a byproduct of that would lead to a cleaner print.

Comment: The extra information is printed because default `Debug` derives print all of the information of your struct. You should probably [impl `Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) for `Asn`, `AsPathSegment`, and `AsPath`.